# problema al imprimir se comprime el texto

Tags: php

Tengo un código de mi trabajo que debo modificar, que imprime tickets en una printer epson del tipo fiscal. No tenía problemas, hasta que necesito agregar un cartel solo en algunos tickets, que denomino rótulo. 
Todo se imprime sobre un png donde ya tengo unas líneas predefinidas y mide 1088px de alto. Lo que hice fue hacer de 1200px el png y me ocurre que todo el texto del ticket se comprime , sea hace algun pixel mas chico . No conozco mucho el tema de impresión pero me gustaría entender porque lo hace ... Mi idea es que imprima las fuentes en el tamaño que yo le doy , que no se achiquen . Copio la función que imprime :

```html
<?php
function genero_tk($vjson)
{
    global $vardir, $vardirdest, $vardirroot, $vardirlog, $file, $vdebug, $impresora;

    $condi     = "N";
    $impresora = ($impresora = "ticketsdes") ? "Terminal 01" : "Terminal Desconocida";
    $font      = $vardir . 'arial.ttf';
    $varsjson  = json_decode($vjson);

    if (!is_numeric($varsjson->{'ticket'})) {
        extit;
    }

    $vnumticket  = $varsjson->{'ticket'};
    $vfecha      = $varsjson->{'fecha'};
    $vpremio     = $varsjson->{'codpremio'};
    $vdescpremio = $varsjson->{'descpremio'};
    $vpuntos     = $varsjson->{'puntos'};
    $vnrosocio   = $varsjson->{'nrosocio'};
    $vnombre     = $varsjson->{'nombre'};
    $vapellido   = $varsjson->{'apellido'};
    $vdni        = $varsjson->{'dni'};
    $entero      = explode(",", $vpuntos);
    $puntos      = $entero[0];

    //leo el código de premio y consulto la leyenda2
    $leyenda2 = file_get_contents("trlleyendas.php?p=" . $vpremio);
    $leyenda2 = trim(strip_tags($leyenda2));
    $condi    = substr($leyenda2, -1);
    $leyenda2 = substr($leyenda2, 0, -1);
    $ticket   = substr($vnumticket, -5);

    //Fecha de Vencimiento
    $fecha      = date('Y-m-j');
    $nuevafecha = strtotime('+30 day', strtotime($fecha));
    $nuevafecha = date('j/m/Y', $nuevafecha);
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_CO.UTF-8');

    //creo codigo de barras
    barcode($vardir . "bc$vnumticket.png", $vnumticket, "100", "horizontal", "Code25", false, 2);

    //Levanto el modelo de ticket
    $dest = imagecreatefrompng($vardir . "ticket.png");

    //Redimencionamos Barcode
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($vardir . "bc$vnumticket.png");
    $rot = imagecreatefrompng($vardir . "rotulo.png");
    imagealphablending($dest, false);
    imagesavealpha($dest, true);

    $lines1 = explode('|', wordwrap($vdescpremio, 32, '|'));
    $lines  = explode('|', wordwrap($leyenda2, 44, '|'));

    $x   = 23;
    $y   = 200;
    $int = 35;

    imagettftext($dest, 19, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, "Fecha: $vfecha");
    $y += $int;
    imagettftext($dest, 19, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, "$puntos puntos");
    $y += $int;
    imagettftext($dest, 19, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, "Socio nro.: $vnrosocio");
    $y += $int;
    imagettftext($dest, 19, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, "$vapellido $vnombre");
    $y += $int;
    imagettftext($dest, 19, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, "DNI: $vdni");
    $y += $int;
    imagettftext($dest, 19, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, "Ticket: $ticket");
    $y += $int;
    imagettftext($dest, 19, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, "Válido hasta el $nuevafecha");
    $y += $int;
    imagettftext($dest, 18, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, " ");
    $y += $int;

    $y = $y - 10;
    foreach ($lines1 as $line1) {
        {
            $line1 = trim($line1);
            $bbox  = imagettfbbox(25, 0, $font, $line1);
            $x     = $bbox[0] + (imagesx($dest) / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2) - 25;
            imagettftext($dest, 25, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, $line1);
            $y += $int;
        }
    }

    imagettftext($dest, 16, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, " ");
    $y += $int;

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $line = trim($line);
        $bbox = imagettfbbox(18, 0, $font, $line);
        $x    = $bbox[0] + (imagesx($dest) / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2) - 25;
        imagettftext($dest, 18, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, $line);
        $y += $int - 5;
    }

    $pie_ticket = trim("Gracias por utilizar nuestra $impresora");
    imagettftext($dest, 18, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, ".");
    $y += $int;

    $bbox = imagettfbbox(18, 0, $font, $pie_ticket);
    $x    = $bbox[0] + (imagesx($dest) / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2) - 25;
    imagettftext($dest, 18, 0, $x, 745, 0, $font, $pie_ticket);

    imagettftext($dest, 18, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, " ");
    $y += $int;
    imagettftext($dest, 18, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, " ");
    $y += $int;
    imagettftext($dest, 18, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, ".");
    $y += $int;
    imagettftext($dest, 18, 0, $x, $y, 0, $font, ".");
    $y += $int;
    imagecopymerge($dest, $src, ((imagesx($dest) - imagesx($src)) / 2) - 20, 770, 0, 0, imagesx($src), imagesy($src), 100);

    if ($condi == "S") {
        imagecopymerge($dest, $rot, ((imagesx($rot) - imagesx($src)) / 2) - 5, 910, 0, 0, imagesx($rot), imagesy($rot), 100);
    }

    imagettftext($dest, 17, 0, 130, 900, 0, $font, "$vnumticket");
    $varchivopng = "$vnumticket-$file.png";
    imagepng($dest, $vardirdest . $varchivopng);
    //echo "La coordenada Y es : " . $y;
    if ($vdebug) {
        echo " guardo:$vardirdest$varchivopng";
    }

    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);
    unlink($vardir . "bc$vnumticket.png");
    rename($vardirroot . $file, $vardirlog . $vnumticket . $file);
    if ($vdebug) {
        echo " rename:$vardirroot$file/$vardirlog$vnumticket$file";
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando dices "se comprime" te refieres a que deja mucho espacio sobrante debajo? Viendo tu código se me ocurre que, si haces una imagen más grande, necesitas adaptar el tamaño de texto y/o el salto de línea (encargado a la variable `$int`). Pero no estoy seguro de haber entendido tu problema en detalle...

Comment: Hola , encontré el problema. El largo lo manejaba un archivo bash externo que no sabía que existía ... lo agrandé unos mm y ya no me achica las fuentes.

Comment: encontré el problema. El largo lo manejaba un archivo bash externo que no sabía que existía ... agrandé unos mm del largo del ticket .. y ya no me achica las fuentes.